# Unknown Column in 'Where Clause' (mysql)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to import a view into my database, doing the following:

```
create algorithm = UNDEFINED 
       definer = `adbo_boletines_3` @`localhost` 
       sql security 
       definer view `adbo_boletines_3`.`postcategories` as 
select
    `p`.`ID` as `ID`,
    `p`.`post_author` as `post_author`,
    `p`.`post_date` as `post_date`,
    `p`.`post_date_gmt` as `post_date_gmt`,
    `p`.`post_content` as `post_content`,
    `p`.`post_title` as `post_title`,
    `p`.`post_excerpt` as `post_excerpt`,
    `p`.`post_status` as `post_status`,
    `p`.`comment_status` as `comment_status`,
    `p`.`ping_status` as `ping_status`,
    `p`.`post_password` as `post_password`,
    `p`.`post_name` as `post_name`,
    `p`.`to_ping` as `to_ping`,
    `p`.`pinged` as `pinged`,
    `p`.`post_modified` as `post_modified`,
    `p`.`post_modified_gmt` as `post_modified_gmt`,
    `p`.`post_content_filtered` as `post_content_filtered`,
    `p`.`post_parent` as `post_parent`,
    `p`.`guid` as `guid`,
    `p`.`menu_order` as `menu_order`,
    `p`.`post_type` as `post_type`,
    `p`.`post_mime_type` as `post_mime_type`,
    `p`.`comment_count` as `comment_count`,
    cast(`p`.`post_date` as date) as `fecha`,
    `r`.`term_taxonomy_id` as `term_taxonomy_id`,
    `t`.`parent` as `parent`,
    `c`.`name` as `name`,
    (
    select
        `cs`.`name`
    from
        ((`wp_term_relationships` `rs`
    join `wp_term_taxonomy` `ts`)
    join `wp_terms` `cs`)
    where
        `rs`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `ts`.`term_taxonomy_id`
        and `ts`.`term_id` = `cs`.`term_id`
        and `ts`.`parent` = 456
        and `rs`.`object_id` = `p`.`ID`
    limit 1) as `pais`
from
    (((`wp_posts` `p`
join `wp_term_relationships` `r`)
join `wp_term_taxonomy` `t`)
join `wp_terms` `c`)
where
    `p`.`ID` = `r`.`object_id`
    and `r`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `t`.`term_taxonomy_id`
    and `t`.`term_id` = `c`.`term_id``term_id`;
```

and getting this error after executing the query

> MySQL said:
>
> #1054 - Unknown column 'c.term_id`term_id' in 'where clause'

im not really sure what to do here, or how to fix the query so it can pass.

thanks!

Comment: you have extra `term_id` at the end in `...AND 't'.'term_id' = 'c'.'term_id''term_id';` , does removing the last `term_id` help..?

Comment: yes, it was this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the is an extra text `term_id` in the end. probably the field in the where clause is `c`.`term_id` only.

that said, change the following sintax:

```
AND `t`.`term_id` = `c`.`term_id``term_id`;
```

to

```
AND `t`.`term_id` = `c`.`term_id`;
```

Comment: There is a standard close reason for questions that are the result of a *typo or cannot be  reproduced*. Please use it instead of answering the question.